# Splitting a dataframe string column based on number of characters in string into multiple different columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split, tidyr, stringr

I am trying to split a character string column into two separate columns based on the first three characters of the string and I can't seem to find the answer that I understand.  I am new to dealing with strings so that might be the issue.

Here's my df:

c("CBR118", "CBR52", "CBR77", "CBR77", "CBR99", "CBR7", "CBR7")

I am trying to separate the "CBR" from the trailing number and add them to new columns in the df.  The CBR stays the same, the trailing number varies in characters from 1 to 3.  I have tried the `stringr` package and the `separate_wider_position` from the `tidyr` package but I can't seem to get it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I chose the answer that uses regular expressions because I would like to use them more frequently in the future but all the answers will work.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tidyr::separate_wider_regex` you could do:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("CBR118", "CBR52", "CBR77", "CBR77", "CBR99", "CBR7", "CBR7")
)

library(tidyr)

df |>
  separate_wider_regex(
    x,
    patterns = c("prefix" = "^CBR", "id" = "\\d+$")
  )
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   prefix id   
#>   <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 CBR    118  
#> 2 CBR    52   
#> 3 CBR    77   
#> 4 CBR    77   
#> 5 CBR    99   
#> 6 CBR    7    
#> 7 CBR    7
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works great and it helps me to start learning about regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(col_name = c("CBR118", "CBR52", "CBR77", "CBR77", "CBR99", "CBR7", "CBR7")) |>
  separate_wider_position(col_name, c("cbr" = 3, "number" = 5), too_few = "align_start") |>
  mutate(number = as.numeric(number))
# # A tibble: 7 × 2
#   cbr   number
#   <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 CBR      118
# 2 CBR       52
# 3 CBR       77
# 4 CBR       77
# 5 CBR       99
# 6 CBR        7
# 7 CBR        7
```

I chose `5` as a guess for the maximum digits there might be in the number. If you might have more digits, you can make it bigger.

Answer (score 2):

in base R:

```
 strcapture("(CBR)(\\d+)", df$x, list(cbr = "", number = 0))

  cbr number
1 CBR    118
2 CBR     52
3 CBR     77
4 CBR     77
5 CBR     99
6 CBR      7
7 CBR      7
```

---

```
data.frame(cbr = 'CBR', number = readr::parse_number(df$x))

  cbr number
1 CBR    118
2 CBR     52
3 CBR     77
4 CBR     77
5 CBR     99
6 CBR      7
7 CBR      7
```

---

```
read.table(text = sub("R", "R ", df$x), col.names = c('cbr', 'number'))
  cbr number
1 CBR    118
2 CBR     52
3 CBR     77
4 CBR     77
5 CBR     99
6 CBR      7
7 CBR      7
```